# many value in one cell divided by space duplicate in R

Tags: r

| name | high_test |
| --- | --- |
| Rober | 45 78 66 89 |
| Kevin | 33 51 51 67 |
| Adelaide | 71 87 60 98 |
| Alexis | 28 28 29 28 |

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = c("Rober", "Kevin", "Adelaide", "Alexis"),
  high_test = c("45 78 66 89","33 51 51 67","71 87 60 98","28 28 29 28"))

> str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ name     : chr  "Rober" "Kevin" "Adelaide" "Alexis"
 $ high_test: chr  "45 78 66 89" "33 51 51 67" "71 87 60 98" "28 28 29 28"
```

value in column `high_test` is divided by space,
I want de- duplicate the same value.

| name | high_test |
| --- | --- |
| Rober | 45 78 66 89 |
| Kevin | 33 51 67 |
| Adelaide | 71 87 60 98 |
| Alexis | 28 29 |

Could someone tell me how can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string on the space, look for unique elements, and paste back together:

```
df$high_test <- lapply(strsplit(df$high_test," "), \(s) paste(unique(s),collapse=" "))
```

Output:

```
      name   high_test
1    Rober 45 78 66 89
2    Kevin    33 51 67
3 Adelaide 71 87 60 98
4   Alexis       28 29
```

An alternative that does the same thing is below:

```
f <- function(s) paste(unique(s),collapse=" ")

dplyr::mutate(df, high_test = lapply(strsplit(high_test," "), f))
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried another way !! It's also work, df$high_test <-  sapply(df$high_test," ", function(x) paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, " "))), collapse = " ")), But I got new function ``` \(s)``` in your code! Thank you!

Comment: Hi again , in your code you used  \(s) paste(unique(s),collapse=" ") is the same as function(x) right? I google the key word \(s) but can get clearly description.

Comment: Yes. In R version >=4.1, you can use `\(x)` as a shortcut for `function(x)`. In the first example above, you can see me use this.. i.e. I used `\(s)` in place of `function(s)`